# Using the ROLLUP function in CASE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, tableau-api, rollup

I have a query where I need to dynamically change the column I perform the `ROLLUP`on. 
So here is the sample data:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
|Location_ID|PLANT    |  ...  |COUNT_IO|TIME_IO|TIME_TARGET_OEE_100_FILTERED|
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
|01105123000|1        |  ...  |10      |50     |75                          |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
|01105123001|1        |  ...  |13      |65     |75                          |      
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
|01105123002|1        |  ...  |15      |75     |65                          |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
|01105123003|1        |  ...  |13      |65     |75                          |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
|01101113001|2        |  ...  |40      |200    |400                         |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
|01101113002|2        |  ...  |20      |100    |400                         |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
```

desired output (`ROLLUP` on `LOCATION_ID`):

```
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|Location_ID|PLANT    |  ...  |COUNT_IO|OEE    |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01105123000|1        |  ...  |10      |66,66  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01105123001|1        |  ...  |13      |86,66  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01105123002|1        |  ...  |15      |115,38 |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01105123003|1        |  ...  |13      |86,66  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|NULL       |1        |  ...  |51      |87,93  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

desired output (`ROLLUP` on `PLANT`):

```
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|Location_ID|PLANT    |  ...  |COUNT_IO|OEE    |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01105123000|1        |  ...  |51      |87,93  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01105123001|1        |  ...  |51      |87,93  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01105123002|1        |  ...  |51      |87,93  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01105123003|1        |  ...  |51      |87,93  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01101113001|2        |  ...  |60      |37,5   |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|01101113002|2        |  ...  |60      |37,5   |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|...        |NULL     |  ...  |111     |50,92  |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

sample code:

```
SELECT
--Dimensions:
  --VALUES_FOR_TABLEAU_METADATA:
    DISTINCT LOCATION_ID,
    CONTINENT, 
    COUNTRY, 
    PLANT,
    BUSINESS_UNIT, 
    PRODUCT,
--Measures (KPI's):
  --Count:
    CASE 
        WHEN <Parameters.BU> = '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN SUM(COUNT_IO) OVER (PARTITION BY BUSINESS_UNIT)
        WHEN <Parameters.BU> != '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN SUM(COUNT_IO) OVER (PARTITION BY PLANT)
        ELSE SUM(COUNT_IO) OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION_ID)
    END AS "COUNT_IO",
  --OEE:
    CASE 
        WHEN TIME_IO = 0 OR TIME_TARGET_OEE_100 = 0
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 
            CASE 
                WHEN <Parameters.BU> = '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN SUM(TIME_IO) OVER (PARTITION BY BUSINESS_UNIT) *100/SUM(TIME_TARGET_OEE_100_FILTERED) OVER (PARTITION BY BUSINESS_UNIT)
                WHEN <Parameters.BU> != '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN SUM(TIME_IO) OVER (PARTITION BY PLANT) *100/SUM(TIME_TARGET_OEE_100_FILTERED) OVER (PARTITION BY PLANT)
                ELSE SUM(TIME_IO) OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION_ID) *100/SUM(TIME_TARGET_OEE_100_FILTERED) OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION_ID)
            END
    END AS "OEE"
FROM VALUES_FOR_TABLEAU_METADATA
WHERE
  COUNT_TARGET_OEE != 0 AND PLANT LIKE <Parameters.Plant> AND BUSINESS_UNIT LIKE <Parameters.BU> AND LOCATION_ID LIKE <Parameters.LocationID> AND WORKING_DAY BETWEEN <Parameters.WorkingDay_Start> AND <Parameters.WorkingDay_End>
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN <Parameters.BU> = '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN LOCATION_ID
        WHEN <Parameters.BU> != '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN LOCATION_ID
        ELSE ROLLUP(LOCATION_ID)
    END,
    CASE 
        WHEN <Parameters.BU> = '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN PLANT
        WHEN <Parameters.BU> != '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN ROLLUP(PLANT)
        ELSE PLANT
    END,
    CASE 
        WHEN <Parameters.BU> = '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN ROLLUP(BUSINESS_UNIT)
        WHEN <Parameters.BU> != '%' AND <Parameters.Plant> = '%' THEN BUSINESS_UNIT
        ELSE BUSINESS_UNIT
    END,
    CONTINENT, COUNTRY, PRODUCT, COUNT_IO, COUNT_TARGET_OEE, TIME_IO, TIME_TARGET_OEE_100, TIME_TARGET_OEE_100_FILTERED
```

I guess that the problem is caused by the `ROLLUP` in the `CASE` statement, since the code up to the `GROUP BY` is working fine. Also I am not quite sure if the usage of my `CASE` statement is used properly.

The Parameters may look quite weird, but they are for use in Tableau and work fine.

The error I get is:

> ORA-00904: "ROLLUP": invalid identifier

Comment: Show us the sample data set  and expected result.There could be simpler ways to accomplish what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: @KaushikNayak sorry it took a while i added sample data if thats understandable...

Comment: The `rollup` keyword has to go outside the `case` expression.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson so there is no way to perform a dynamic `ROLLUP`?

Comment: Yes, but only by writing a `case` expression that returns the aggregation key that allows the rollup you want, or by rolling up at more levels than you need and filtering at the end somehow. I haven't worked through your complex mcve though so I can't advise on how to do that.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I tried to nest the `case` inside the `rollup` but now i get a `ORA-00979: `not a GROUP BY expression` error, since it appears that the `CASE` does not get recognized properly...

Comment: Perhaps a simplified test case would help.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to work with Tableau is to let it generate optimized SQL based on what you express in Tableau. Don't use custom SQL with Tableau except in rare situations. You get a lot more flexibility and performance that way.

In this case, I recommend just connecting to VALUES_FOR_TABLEAU_METADATA from Tableau.

1. Define a string valued parameter to allow the user to choose the dimension for his "rollup", say called **Dimension_For_Rollup** with a list of two possible values: "Location" and "Plant".
2. Define a calculated field called **Selected_Dimension** defined as `if [Dimension_For_Rollup] = "Location" then [Location Id] else [Plant] end`
3. Use Selected_Dimension on your viz as desired.
4. Show the parameter control for Dimension_For_Rollup

So the user can toggle between Dimensions for Rollup as he wishes, and Tableau will generate optimized SQL, cache the query as needed.

Your Count_IO or Time_IO stats can be expressed in different ways in Tableau, possible needing Tableau's level of detail (LOD) calcs, but again -- your Tableau experience will be better if you don't try to hard code everything in SQL in advance. You *can* use Tableau that way, but you're making life hard on yourself and giving up a good part of the benefit.